# I want to match the type of message labels containing "_" in i18next ・react-i18next

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, i18next, react-i18next

"i18next":"^23.5.1", "react-i18next":"^13.2.2" is used.

To be able to extract unique text from message Json labels, referring to the section on TypeScript in the documentation. (cf. https://www.i18next.com/overview/typescript)

```
// To make i18next read the type of message Json

import MessageData from '@public/messages/message_en.json'

declare module 'i18next' {
  interface CustomTypeOptions {
    resources: {
      translation: typeof MessageData
    }
  }
}
```

```
// my message json file
{
  "profile": {
    "payment_information": "Payment Information"
  }
}
```

The above code makes i18next read Json, but when we check the type, it contains a type where "_" is converted to "n". What is the solution to this problem?

[image]